# How do you understand the output of re.pm when debug turned on?

Tags: regex, perl

```
[root@ test]# perl -e 'use re "debug";"a" =~ /.*/';
Compiling REx `.*'
size 3 Got 28 bytes for offset annotations.
first at 2
   1: STAR(3)
   2:   REG_ANY(0)
   3: END(0)
anchored(MBOL) implicit minlen 0 
Offsets: [3]
    2[1] 1[1] 3[0] 
Matching REx ".*" against "a"
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=3
   0 <> <a>               |  1:  STAR
                           REG_ANY can match 1 times out of 2147483647...
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=3
   1 <a> <>               |  3:    END
Match successful!
Freeing REx: `".*"'`
```

Anyone can interpret this?

Answer (score 6):

The output has two important parts: pattern compilation and runtime matching.

The first part describes the nodes, of which there are three, in the compiled automaton.

- `STAR(n)` matches zero or more of the following node and continues through node *n*.
- `REG_ANY` matches any character except newline (*i.e.*, `/./`)
- `END` marks the end state of the automaton.

`MBOL` matches beginning-of-line in multiline match mode, *i.e.*, `/^/m`. This is there implicitly because of the `.*` at the beginning of your pattern. (Remember: regex quantifiers are greedy by default.)

The minimum length of a string that can match your pattern is zero, or the empty string. (Remember: the `*` quantifier *always* succeeds!)

Offsets are of the form

```
NODENUM:POSITION[LENGTH]
```

and link nodes to the regex in your program. In your case, `.*` (nodes 2 and 1) begins at the first position in your pattern, and the end state is there implicitly. Offsets handy for regex debuggers, *e.g.*, to highlight which subpattern is currently attempting to match.

Now that it's compiled, it can be matched, and the latter part traces the execution. The [Pragmas and Debugging section of the perlretut documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Pragmas-and-debugging) explains the form of the lines that describe match progress:

> Each step is of the form `n <x> <y>`, with `<x>` the part of the string matched and `<y>` the part not yet matched.

The match in your question begins with no text consumed, then `.*` matches `a`, and the pattern matches successfully.

The eval scope is machinery related to [executable code in regexes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%7b-code-%7d%29), which you don't use.

The [Debugging Regular Expressions section of the perldebguts documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html#Debugging-Regular-Expressions) gives more background information, and, as always, use the source, Luke!

Comment: It seems the only thing we can get from the output is that regex is interpreted from right-most. Is that anything else useful there?